# Slicing Images on Gimp

Tags: gimp, adobe-fireworks

When slicing an image on Gimp is there a way to slice using rectangular selections, similar to how Adobe Fireworks functions? I'm looking for a free alternative to FW for work just in case I can't access it from home. In FW, you're able to slice an image up into smaller images and export them as an HTML file with nested tables. I've discovered you can almost do this in Gimp but it seems I'm restricted to only using vertical and horizontal "guides" that cut through the whole image, which is what I don't want. Is there a way to have varied box selections for slicing? I've tried all sorts of video tutorials and looked through the Gimp docs and nothing seems to lead me to believe this is possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might explain the "slicing" operation in more detail, as it might not exist or be named differently in GIMP. And have you seen https://gimp4you.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/guillotine-the-gimp-way-to-slice-images/ ?

Comment: Slicing is just basically cutting up an image to make smaller images, in my case, I want to do this and export the images as nested HTML tables. This can be done, for the most part, with gimp but you are restricted to using guides the cut through the entire image from edge to edge, which is not what I want. Similar to functionality of adobe fireworks slicing tool, I want the ability define my own rectangular cuts. The following tutorial should elaborate on what I need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq-7dDVCCCA. This may not be a feature for gimp 2.8. Maybe there's a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge GIMP only comes with the basic [slicing](https://docs.gimp.org/en/python-fu-slice.html) functionality using [guides](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html).

According to this [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162257) the slicing functionality may have been implemented in [gimp#](http://gimp-sharp.sourceforge.net/), which has not been updated for a while and may not be compatible with GIMP 2.8, but you could give it a try.

As an alternative the GIMP documentation suggests using [ImageMap](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-imagemap.html):

> The ImageMap filter is a much more powerful and sophisticated tool for creating sensitive images. (But it is also much more complex...)